# Google Game Play Service - Capture User cancelled the sign-in

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an android app where the user have to sign in to post there score in the leaderboard. When the user cancels the sign-in I need to capture that and remember it so that I will not disturb him again for the sign-in.

Could you please let me know how to find if the user has selected the cancel request in the Activity when extending the BaseGameActivity.

Kindly Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I got it. I have created 1 more listener in GameHelper Class in the name of onSignInCancelled() and set up a notifier mListener.onSignInCancelled(); This works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep a simple boolean in your `SharedPreferences` object when the cancel is detected.

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(CANCEL_LOGIN, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...
if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(DID_CANCEL_LOGIN, false)
{
    //Don't show login.
}
else
{ 
    //Show login.
}
...
public void onCancel()
{
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(DID_CANCEL_LOGIN, true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: How to find if the user has given the cancel request

Comment: @iappmaker Taking a quick look at the BaseGameActivity class on the hard drive here in the Android package, I don't see a component designed into it that involves a sign-in.  Where is the sign-in component?

Comment: I am not sure. But I guess I need to use the variable mSignInCancelled in the GameHelper Class